# How can I display date and time each of my tab sheets were 'last updated'?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have multiple tab sheets and I want to have a cell on each tab sheet that automatically displays the date & time that particular tab sheet was updated (each tab needs to be independent from one another). How can I modify the script below so that I can have a 'last updated' cell for each of my tab sheets?

```
function onEdit(e) {
var watchedSheet = 'Sheet1',
    watchedRange = {
        "startRow": 2,
        "endRow": 12,
        "startCol": 3,
        "endCol": 29
    },
    stampCell = 'K2',
    activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
if (activeSheet.getName() !== watchedSheet || e.range.rowStart > watchedRange.endRow || e.range.columnStart < 2 && e.range.columnStart > watchedRange.endCol || !e.value) return;
activeSheet.getRange(stampCell).setValue(new Date());}
```

Comment: Have you tried the suggested solution?

Answer (score 0):

It can be something like this, is suppose:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var watchedRange = {
        "startRow": 2,
        "endRow": 12,
        "startCol": 3,
        "endCol": 29
      },
      stampCell = 'K2';
  if (e.range.rowStart > watchedRange.endRow || e.range.columnStart < 2 && e.range.columnStart > watchedRange.endCol || !e.value) return;
  e.source.getRange(stampCell).setValue(new Date());
}
```